# Testing BPEL processes?

Tags: testing, tdd, bpel

I am considering to use BPEL for my next project. I played around with the Netbeans BPEL designer and I am happy with it. But before I decide to use BPEL I want to know how well it is suited for test driven developing. Unfortunately I found very little about that topic. Can someone with experience in BPEL point me to some testing tutorials? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BPEL Unit](http://www.bpelunit.net) is taylormade for testing BPEL processes. It provides an Eclipse-based UI for designing test cases and provides runners for Ant and Maven2 for automated testing. BPEL Unit also allows for mocking external services, i.e. BPEL Unit simulates the behavioral interface of third party services and tests whether it is being used correctly by the BPEL process under test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Netbeans, but in general it depends on the [BPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_management) or workflow engine. BPEL is just the language.

Based on a search, there do appear to be tools for testing BPEL process maps directly. See for example [b-unit](http://infocenter.activevos.com/infocenter/ActiveVOS/v70/topic/com.activee.bpel.doc/html/UG21-1.html).

I'd recommend writing integration tests against the BPM engine as well.